# Pass a specific variable from a dict to a function (Python 3)

Tags: python-3.x, function, dictionary

Seriously learned so much from this site but now I have my own question!

I am still pretty new but I am trying to take input from the user, find the input (as a hotkey) within the dict, and then use/pass that specific hotkey in the function that the dict redirects to. Hope that makes sense. Here is what I've tried so far:

First I ask the user for a command:

```
command_input = input(prompt).lower()
    for i in all_commands:
        if command_input in all_commands[i]["hotkey"]:
            all_commands[i]["function"](hero)
            break
```

Then I'll lookup the input from the "hotkey" field in the dict:

```
all_commands = {
    1:  {"command_name" :   "north",
         "description"  :   "Travel north.",
         "hotkey"       :   "n",
         "function"     :   Character.navigate},
    2:  {"command_name" :   "east",
         "description"  :   "Travel east.",
         "hotkey"       :   "e",
         "function"     :   Character.navigate},
}
```

So far so good. I can find the field, and call the associated function no problem. However, I want to just have one function, that specifically uses the "command_name" that was associated with that "hotkey". I could just have a specific function for each dict entry (e.g. Character.navigate_east vs navigate_north) but I don't want to have 4 different navigate functions.

How do I pass the specific "command_name" to the following function? I do not want to have to require the command (some functions won't ask for it) but I want it if I need it. I will eventually need to parse out different things like "get object", etc and need to get different variables for different functions.

```
def navigate(self, **all_commands):
    direction = all_commands["command_name"]

    if direction in self.current_room["exits"]:
        self.current_room = rooms[self.current_room["exits"][direction]]
        Room.room_description(self)
    else:
        print (f"You can't go {direction}.")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working version of your example. Changed only minimally, and added a simple function to make it full working demo script.

- Added `prompt` variable.
- Removed 'Character.' part of the name of the function
- I did not know what to do with `hero`, so I removed it to maken thinkgs work.
- Removed `**all_commands` from the function parameter list. As far as I can see, this is not needed.
- Call the function with `all_commands[i]["command_name"]` as argument.

Code:

```
def navigate(command):
    print("Command is:", command)

all_commands = {
    1:  {"command_name" :   "north",
         "description"  :   "Travel north.",
         "hotkey"       :   "n",
         "function"     :   navigate},
    2:  {"command_name" :   "east",
         "description"  :   "Travel east.",
         "hotkey"       :   "e",
         "function"     :   navigate},
}

prompt="command:> "
command_input = input(prompt).lower()
for i in all_commands:
    if command_input in all_commands[i]["hotkey"]:
        all_commands[i]["function"](all_commands[i]["command_name"])
        break
```

Comment: I made an edit to specify that I don't want to HAVE to pass it through, but only do so if I need it. I tried using **kwargs but I don't think I understand it enough to do so correctly. This way does raise the "1 needed, 2 given." Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: In the functions that do not need the "command_name" argument, you can just ignore it. The thing is: the command lookup loop where the function is called cannot know if it needs to pass an argument (like "command_name") or not.

Comment: Hmm, not sure I understand. You say I can just ignore it, but if a function I'm calling doesn't ask for the command, then it raises the problem that I've given it, but I'm not asking for it (1 needed, 2 given). Sometimes I may be passing one value, sometimes 2, sometimes 3, etc. but only the first word will ever be checked in the commands (however I will need the remaining words to be used in the function it calls).

Comment: This does slightly answer better as it takes the code as is, but I'll add that Ixop's remark about adding the flags really helped complete what I was trying to do. Hate to have to pick as you guys both helped me tremendously. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Quite simple:

```
command_input = input(prompt).lower()
    for _, command in all_commands.items():
        if command_input in command["hotkey"]:
            command["function"](hero, command_name=command["command_name"])
            break

def navigate(hero, command_name):
    #...
```

where I have also simplified your loop through the dictionary to make it read a little better (using `.items()`).

Comment: I considered adding the command_name after hero, but if I don't want/need to pass it through, then it asks for that variable in functions that don't request it. I have a number of different commands and some of them do not require the actual command. I'm also not sure I understand how the "_, command" works. Could you explain that?

Comment: If you're going to call the action function from a lookup, then you will need all the functions to have the same interface, so for functions that don't need it, they will just have an unused command_name parameter. If you really don't like that, you could add more complexity and add a flag to the dicts in all_commands that identifies whether the command name is expected.

Comment: For the `_, command` part, you can iterate through `dict.items()`, and each iteration will produce `key, value`. So in this case you are not using the key (so I just used `_` for it), and the interesting dict is named `command` which is then easier to read

Comment: Good idea on the flag key!